# Is there a way to create two entries into separate sql database tables that are linked by a foreign key?

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, triggers, unit-of-work

I am currently trying to create an entry in a SQL table using ASP.NET Core and LINQ, then create entries in another table where these new entries have a foreign key pointing to the first entry I have just created.

All the entries seem to create just fine however the latter entries have foreign keys set to `Null` when I look at them in the database. I started with the creation of the entries in the same 'Unit Of Work' and have since tried to split them out into two Units of Work.

All this is begin run as a background job using **Hangfire**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about SQL purely, I would create a trigger that meets the conditions on the tables to update the corresponding entries, as I don't see any code, I can't give you an piece of code.
For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

I think that the problem is that at the time that your problematic entries are entered into the database, the foreign keys (primary key in another table) are not set yet, they don't have a value yet.

If you are using entity framework, this can be sorted, or you can add triggers to the database so, when the entry is created, you can look into the other table to get its primary key (foreign key) and modify it